# iOS connect my view to popup on button press

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have two xibs, one is my title screen with buttons, the other is a more specific window that should come up when one of the buttons is pressed.

This isn't switching the whole screen, just a popup window, where clicking outside of the bounds of that window will make it disappear leaving only my title screen remaining as it was visible behind this popup view. This is similar to my understanding of "modal views".

Anyway I do not quite get how to connect it to the button on my title screen. I have the views made in IB ready to go. I'm not sure if I have declared all objects to satisfaction yet.

From what I understand I think I need a UIViewController or something, but its all a pretty thick fog of information right now

insight appreciated, or links to proper noob sources would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your title screen have a view controller (or is your app delegate the main controller object)? You will want to add an IBAction to that object, connect the button to it, and then present your other view controller modally (or in a popover) from there.

A popover will appear in a small window with an arrow, and tapping outside will close it. A modal view controller typically slides up into place, and you have to press a cancel button to close it. [This guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/iPadControllers/iPadControllers.html) explains how to use a popover. Using a modal view controller is simple if you have a view controller: `[myViewController presentModalViewController:nextViewController animated:YES]`.

Comment: the button is connected (I made it change the background of the title screen onclick earlier), I dont get how to connect it to the next popup view. Elaborate on what "present your other view controller modally" means and how this is done.        also What is the difference between modally and popover